# Woocomerce ajax call retun home page HTML in response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

Suddenly when I go to the Apply coupon by clicking on the "Apply Coupon" button in cart page. Then I saw the homepage design on the cart page. I don't know what's wrong with the Woocommerce suddenly. Also when I go to the checkout page and fill up the details then also shipping charges not calculating. I think something wrong with the Woocommerce ajax.

Anybody help me out, please.

Comment: have you inspected any of the ajax requests? response statuses, errors being returned? Logs showing any issues?

Comment: I got response status "301 Moved Permanently"

Comment: can you access the page otherwise? Have you modified htaccess or any other rewrites or routing? Have you recently switched to HTTPS?

Comment: I have code .htaccess code to redirect HTTPS.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that woo commerce is sending ajax requests to a non HTTPS page. If you look at the first request, does it go to `http://`?
if so, when the page is redirected, the post data is being lost. You need to update the code to ensure https is being used for all URLS.

Comment: No. Ajax call fire the request with the "https://" . All URLS having the HTTPS.

Comment: and that initial https request has a status of 301? Where does it 301 to? Could you check the link in the page source to confirm its https. You might not be seeing the original http request.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution on this issue. There was anotherplugin had the issue after updating plugin. So I have disabled the plugin and it worked.